# Quartz Job not triggering from IIS Server and not inserting jobs into database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cron, quartz-scheduler, backgroundworker, job-scheduling

I have done schedule jobs and jobs running on Visual studio 2022

```
public class NotificationJob : IHostedService
{
    readonly ILogger<NotificationJob> _logger;
  //  private  IScheduler _scheduler;

    public NotificationJob(ILogger<NotificationJob> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service started..!");


        try {
            await NotificationJob1();
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while scheduling notification jobs.");
        }
       
       
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service stopped..!");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    //private async Task ConfigurationQuartzScheduler()
    //{
    //    var data = new NameValueCollection
    //        {
    //            // ... (other configurations)

    //            // Configure the ADO.NET Job Store
    //            { "quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" },
    //            { "quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "default" },
    //            { "quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" },
    //            { "quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString", "Data Source=DESKTOP-4IJOIDT;Initial Catalog=CronJobsDB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=true" }, // Specify your connection string
    //            { "quartz.jobStore.JobsTable.dbo", "QRTZ_" }
    //        };

    //    var schedulerData = new StdSchedulerFactory(data);
    //    _scheduler = await schedulerData.GetScheduler();
    //    await _scheduler.Start();
    //}


    private async Task NotificationJob1()
    {
        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
        var scheduler = await schedulerFactory;
        await scheduler.Start();
        

        // Define the job
        var job = JobBuilder.Create<BackgroundWorkerJob>()
            .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJob", "DefaultGroup")
            
            .Build();

        // Define multiple triggers with different time intervals
        var triggers = new List<ITrigger>
        {
    //--------------------------------------- NOTIFICATION 0 ---------------------------------------- 

            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJobTrigger0", "DefaultGroup")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(13,18,0)) // 10:19 PM Today
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24) // Repeat every 24 hours
                .RepeatForever())
                .Build(),
    //--------------------------------------- NOTIFICATION 1  ---------------------------------------- 
            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJobTrigger1", "DefaultGroup")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(13,20,0)) // 6:30 PM Today
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24) // Repeat every 24 hours
                .RepeatForever())
                .Build(),

  

            // Add more triggers as needed
        };

        // Schedule the job with multiple triggers
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, triggers,true); // 'true' means to replace existing triggers if any
        
    }
```

```
 public class BackgroundWorkerJob : IJob
 {

     public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
     {
         try
         {
             string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-4IJOIDT;Database=CronJobsDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;TrustServerCertificate=true";

             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
             {
                 await con.OpenAsync(); // Use async OpenAsync method

                 using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                 {
                     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO JobsTable (JobType, JobName, CronExpression) VALUES (@JobType, @JobName, @CronExpression)";
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobType", "test");
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobName", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CronExpression", DateTime.Now.ToString());

                     // No need to check ConnectionState again, as it's opened in the using block
                     await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                 }
                 con.CloseAsync();
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            throw ex;
         }
     }

 }
```

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Data Source=DESKTOP-4IJOIDT;Initial Catalog=CronJobsDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;TrustServerCertificate=true");
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<NotificationJob>();


builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(c=> c.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJob, BackgroundWorkerJob>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StdSchedulerFactory>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory,StdSchedulerFactory>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHostedService,NotificationJob>();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();




builder.Services.AddQuartz(configure =>
{
    configure.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    configure.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        s.UseProperties = true;
        
    });
});



builder.Services.AddQuartz(configure =>
{
    configure.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();
    
    // Configure your jobs and triggers here
    // ...
    
});




var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
//{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
//}
//app.UseExceptionHandler("C://inetpub//wwwroot//CJobs//Error");
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();


app.Run();
```

Hey This code of Quartz cron jobs are working on my machine,But when publish on IIS or Server,It's not triggering jobs and jobs not inserting into database after hosting.I am getting swagger view also,I am not getting solution for this.What to do?.